# Can an global action be included into another navigation file?

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

Let's consider MyDestination a destination to a Fragment and MyAction a global action containing animations and navigating to MyDestination.

Since I needed MyDestination and MyAction in 2 different navigation files, I decided to create a 3rd navigation file containing those 2 items, and include it.

Problem is, I keep getting "is unknown to this NavController" exceptions if I try to navigate with MyAction (through id or generated classes)

Only thing I can do right now is only include MyDestination, and duplicate MyAction in the 2 different navigation files.

Is it actually possible to include global actions then?